# Old app to support for iPhone X?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-x

My old iOS app works well in all iPhone versions(Except iPhone X model). I run into iPhone X simulator and seeing some of the screens gets overlapped at bottom of iPhone X screen. My apps all uiviewcontrollers created programmatically, not designed by story board. So in all view controllers I used (self.view.frame) to find its frame size. In iPhoneX there is safe guard area to design in story board. But how do I calculate safe guard area in runtime. While searching google it gives some sample to find safe guard area which is support from iOS11.. But I want to run my app from ios9? I have lot of uiviewcontrollers in my project .. So can anyone tell me an easiest way to do this task?

Comment: How about iPhone 8?

Comment: Have you added splash screen image of 1125px × 2436px?

Comment: added splash screen image. But still issues accured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to add a run-time fix for iPhone X layout issues to old (pre-storyboard manual layout) apps (with old pre-11 Deployment targets), is to add Objective C code similar to:

```
CGRect r0 = self.view.frame;
CGRect r1 = r0;
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    r1 = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame;     
}
if ( r1.size.height < (r0.size.height - 20.0) ) {
    // fix top and bottom view overlap outside safe area here
}
```

inside each UIViewController's viewWillLayoutSubviews method.

The @available check will make this code safe to use under iOS versions prior to iOS 11.

Comment: I have xcode8.2.. i am going to create new iOS app and UI Design using storyboard...  I want to run my app without issue in iPhoneX. How can I do it using xcode8.2? Will it be possible? or I must need xcode9.

Comment: You do need Xcode 9 in order to support the iPhone X. Because Xcode 8.x is not aware of the new device and the App has black bands on top and bottom of the app's view port.